# Map values using multiple columns with a specific condition in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset where I would like to map values based on a specific condition.
I would like to add a new column and then map a label to an ID if it meets the condition of:

```
**If ID == AA AND Date >= to Q121:  Status = 'closed' AND values within the Used column will be null.**
```

**Data**

```
ID  Date    Location    Used    
AA  Q121    NY          20  
AA  Q221    NY          50  
AA  Q321    NY          10  
BB  Q121    CA          1   
BB  Q221    CA          0   
BB  Q321    CA          500 
BB  Q421    CA          700 
CC  Q121    AZ          50
```

**Desired**

```
ID  Date    Location    Used    Status
AA  Q121    NY                  closed
AA  Q221    NY                  closed
AA  Q321    NY                  closed
BB  Q121    CA          1   
BB  Q221    CA          0   
BB  Q321    CA          500 
BB  Q421    CA          700 
CC  Q121    AZ          50
```

**Doing**

```
df['Status']=df['ID'].map({'AA':'closed' ,  })
```

Is it possible to map using two columns, or would a loop be better fit for this?
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for this:

```
df['Used'] = np.where(((df.ID == 'AA') & (df.Date >= 'Q121')), '', df['Used'])
df['Status'] = np.where(((df.ID == 'AA') & (df.Date >= 'Q121')), 'closed', '')

# or use np.nan instead of '' above, that's actually preferable (generating NaN values)

print(df)

   ID  Date Location   Used  Status
0  AA  Q121       NY         closed
1  AA  Q221       NY         closed
2  AA  Q321       NY         closed
3  BB  Q121       CA    1.0        
4  BB  Q221       CA    0.0        
5  BB  Q321       CA  500.0        
6  BB  Q421       CA  700.0        
7  CC  Q121       AZ   50.0
```

Comment: You could also opt for `np.nan` (i.e. `NaN` float, recommended instead of `None`) instead of `''` used above (i.e. an empty string).